# jQuery animation displayed only if page is loaded centered on the element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this jQuery snippet:

```
$(window).one('scroll', function(){
        // scroll
        $('.hidemenot').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */


             if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){   
                $(this).css('opacity', 0).one()
                 .slideDown('slow')
                 .animate(
                  { opacity: 1 },
                  { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }, 1500
                  );
             }

        });
    });
```

Which is supposed to slidedown + fadeIn some elements the first time the user scrolls. However, if I load the page normally, nothing shows up. But when I scroll to the section where it's supposed to be, and then reload, it shows up with the animation because I'm already on the section.

What did I do wrong here ? the `$(window).one('scroll'` is supposed to handle scrolling.

Comment: one will only execute the very first time you scroll ... then nothing happens bottom of window propably will be always higher than bottom object. Since you just scroll 1px...

Comment: Yes it only executes once, which is what I want. However, it doesn't execute at all when I load the page normally from the top, even when I scroll down to this section

Comment: It only shows up when I reload "facing" the section

Comment: As I said after you scroll the first px the event doesn't fire any more if you scroll down to the section then doesn't matter the function isn't executed after the first pixel scrolled

Comment: Ok so how can I wait for the scroll to be at the level of the element before firing the animation, but still fire only once ?